# Refresh a PHP Mysqli query after a duration, for loop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a list of 10 random images on my websites home page, currently, these are set to refresh and display another 10 random images in a different order each time that the page is refreshed. The idea of this is so that the user sees different images each time the site is visited.

I would like it so that the images only refresh and show another random 10 images after a certain duration, for example, every 10 minutes, this would need to be for all users, so regardless of what time the user accessed the website the images would refresh the same time for all users, ie, 12-10, 12-20, 12-30....

I have done quite a bit of research on how I could achieve this, as far as I am aware there is nothing which can be added to the actual query.

Another possibility is to use a for loop counter, this just seems greatly inefficient, though.

Here is the query I currently have :

```
$res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
            while($row=$res->fetch_array())
            {
                include 'includes/tile.php'; 

            }
```

Basically i would just like this query to execute once every 10 mins server wide instead of on page refresh.

Any help, or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Call a script with cron to create an html file with images every 10 minutes, then just include the html file in the page

Comment: Can you possibly give me any idea to how this is done ? Thanks again

Comment: for the cron look here [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) which has some useful information on it. Regarding the html file you'll want to use [`output buffers`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) and save the output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK to make it the same for all users, then you can just check the minute value of the current date and make it a switch value based on that. For example, if the current datetime is between 10 and 15, $my_var = foo.